# Call COM/WMI from a DLL independently and isolated from the Host App

Tags: c++, dll, wmi

I made a ***Wrapper DLL*** in ***C++*** that exposes some functions which when invoked connect to ***WMI*** and execute some methods there.

The problem is that it's unknown if the ***Host Application*** has or will call `CoInitialize/Ex` or not, therefore I'm seeking for some kind of a ***Isolated/Sandboxed*** approach to have the ***DLL*** running it's own ***COM/WMI*** independent from the Host App.

I'm still not completely familiar with ***C++ threading models***, but is it possible to have multiple independent ***COM/WMI*** instances in a *DLL*?

From what I could think up to overcome this problem is:

Build an external App that connects to ***COM/WMI*** and allows to make the calls using shared memory. The ***DLL*** could be then just communicating with the shared memory section. (Is it possible to call methods or functions using shared memory?). Downside of this would be the requirement of having an other process running to act as **middleman** to communicate with ***WMI*** and it doesn't seems to be the best way to achieve this.

It would be much better if it would be possible directly from the *DLL*.

Is it possible to create an independent ***COM/WMI*** setup to have `CoInitialize/Ex` run in the scope of the ***DLL*** independent from the Host App? Any advice how to solve this problem?

Greetings and thanks.

Comment: [OLE initialization is a per-thread state](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140821-00/?p=183/), so you achieve "an independent COM setup" by creating another thread.

Comment: It isn't exactly "unknown", you'll get CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED when it wasn't done.  Never hide an initialization mistake, just pass it back to the caller so that programmer knows what to do about it.  Writing threaded code when you are not familiar with threading is a hundred times harder to get right.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg, that's exactly what I've been looking for.